# VBA code stops after Documents.Open

Tags: vba, ms-word

This Word VBA code stops after executing the statement before the 'STOPS HERE' comment.

```
Public Sub Test_Main()

    ' Open the Word file
    Dim sourceDocPath As String
    sourceDocPath = ThisDocument.Path & "\TestDoc.docx"
    Dim sourceDoc As Document
    Set sourceDoc = Documents.Open(sourceDocPath, ReadOnly:=True)
    ' !!!! STOPS HERE !!!!

    MsgBox "GOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOAAAAAAAAAAAALLLL!!!"

    Set sourceDoc = Nothing

    End

End Sub
```

• The specified Word file opens by the statement before the stop point.
• There's no error messages. It just stops after opening the file.
• When run from its own "Document_Open" of the Word macro, the "Test_Main" runs ok to the end. It stops when run directly from "Developer > Macros".
• "Set object = nothing" didn't solve the problem. 
• "End" statement didn't solve the problem.
• Please place "TestDoc.docx" in the same directly as the test Word macro. It can be empty.
• The environment is Office 365 & Windows 10 64 bit.

If anyone has experienced the same kind of problems or knows how to solve the problem, please let me know!

Comment: Are you closing the document again between runs?

Comment: Yes. I close the target Word document before running the macro again.

Comment: What is the version of Office and is it fully updated?

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. Note that to "answer" someone in comments you need to "ping" them: @ImsorryDaveImafraidIcantdothat so that they know you've reacted. FWIW another person reports the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51652227/vba-code-stops-whenever-i-open-a-document so we may be looking at an issue with an Office update...

Comment: FWIW I can't repro. Running Office 365 Version 1808 Build 10711.20012

Comment: @ImsorryDaveImafraidIcantdothat we are seeing something similar using documents.add Try downgrading office version to 1806 - 10228.20104  that fixes it with our clients

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-msoffice_custom-mso_2016/1807-build-1032520082-is-causing-vba-problems-with/538e8c3c-355e-47a7-9e3f-58cf04902c10?tm=1533213042907

Comment: @Rich Michaels The version is Office 365 Version 1807 (Build 10325.20082) on Win 10 64 bit.

Answer (score 2):

According to this article, this seems to be a bug of Word Version 1807 (Build 10325.20082). We may need to downgrade Word to avoid this problem.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-msoffice_custom-mso_2016/1807-build-1032520082-is-causing-vba-problems-with/538e8c3c-355e-47a7-9e3f-58cf04902c10?tm=1533213042907

**Workaround:**
As far as I tested, somehow the code runs ok without stopping when run from its own "Document_Open".

**Progress:**
I noticed on 2018/08/20 that somehow the problem doesn't reproduce now. The version of my Word has not been changed since I had this problem, which is Version 1807 (Build 10325.20082).

Comment: Is your Office version 32-bit or 64-bit? I have a suspicion that the problem may only be occurring in the 64-bit version of Office.

Comment: @Rich Michaels Mine is 64-bit. I wonder how such a simple and critical error can be made and released anyway..

Answer (score 1):

I suffered this bug with Word build 1807. An IT professional helped me downgrade to build 1806, and turned Auto-Upgrade off. This has now restored sensible behaviour, but I have to leave Auto-Upgrade off until Microsoft has issued a build which doesn't have this egregious bug in it.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten report from MVP's at the forums of microsoft that they did a server sided change to a configuration file that word downloads during startup of word. The change makes it so, so that the (new) problematic code causing (my documents.add) problem gets disabled.

I just tested it with a client that had the problem and were we downgraded the office version to the previous build and now the problem as far i could tell seems to be solved.

It could be if you update your office version again it also works with you. Potentially if the problem still occurs the 1st time you need to close word wait a bit and start again.

Maybe it is now also fixed for the documents.open problem with this (server sided) change.

More info in original discution here 
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-msoffice_custom-mso_2016/1807-build-1032520082-is-causing-vba-problems-with/538e8c3c-355e-47a7-9e3f-58cf04902c10

Comment: I am running once again on the latest build and the problem appears resolved on my system for both Document.Add and Document.Open scenarios. MS is still a bit cautious to say that it is fully fixed, it was somewhat more complex than originally thought.

Comment: Rich is the fix applied again using a server sided change ? like it was done previously ? If so when was this applied as we had gotten a few new clients with the problem last week (i think on thursday according to my collegues)