# VBA code stops whenever I open a document

Tags: vba, ms-word

First of all sorry for posting this, I know it's probably duplicated from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51625995/vba-code-stops-after-documents-open) post, I tried to post it as an edit but it got rejected and I can't comment because I don't have 50 reputation, also this is not a proper answer. Hope this helps to get a better understanding of the problem and more attention.

I work in a company that uses VBA and we've been using `Documents.Open` for a long time and it never gave me any problems, until now. The problem seems rather random, as not many clients have this, but it's turning more consistent now mainly with Office 365. Maybe it's due to an actualization?

Whenever I do `Documents.Open` the requested document will open, but anything that comes after that won't be executed. It can be as simple as:

```
Sub Test()
    Documents.Open(filename)
    MsgBox "Hi"
End Sub
```

And the message box will never be shown. I've also tried this, as I found something related in other forums:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim doc as Document
    set doc = Documents.Open(filename)
    MsgBox "Hi"
End Sub
```

I've even tried the old open `WordBasic.FileOpen()`. Nothing helps, code stops executing after opening the document. In a desperated attempt at making this work, I've created a COM dll that opens a document, with a message box in the dll and in VBA after the dll has done it's part. The dll functions properly but as soon as it gets back to VBA the code stops and it doesn't show the message box.

I've done some research and it has nothing to do with the known [shift-key bug](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/555263) since I can run the example code by pressing the play button, so no keys are being pressed when the document opens.

Then I tried to work with the AutoOpen event as seen in [this other post](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/PseudoAutoMacros.htm) and by debbuging I've realized that the `PseudoAutoOpen` event it's never called in the computers with the problem.

Also made sure that everything it's in the trusted documents location and that the macros are enabled, as this other post said:
[Word 2013 VBA - opening document aborts macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28343536/word-2013-vba-opening-document-aborts-macro)

**UPDATE**

I've found out accidentally while debugging, that if I run the example macro twice, the second time (with the targeted document opened) it works as intended.

I'm starting to lose my mind over this.

Comment: FWIW I can't repro. Running Office 365 Version 1808 Build 10711.20012

Comment: @CindyMeister I have Office 365 Version 1807 Build 10325.20082. I notice that your version is higher but when I try to update it it says that there are no updates.

Comment: I'm on an "insider fast" track, meaning I get some "beta bits" before they're released, generally. That's not something a company necessarily wants to have :-) Another thing you might look at is if the file location (network, local, etc.) might have any influence. But, quite frankly, this might be something you need to kick up to Microsoft Support.

Comment: @CindyMeister I've disabled all kind of security measures to be sure that nothing gets in the way. Right now I'm scaning for new system updates just to be sure. I'll update the post with the results and if nothing works we'll have to hit up Microsoft Support. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @CindyMeister - I can reproduce this problem in that build and have reported it to the product team.

Comment: Thanks @RichMichaels. Nasty one...

Comment: We have the same problem in our environment and It happens only when we disable the macro execution (apart the signed ones). Is it possible that this problem is still present after so many months? I read the forum's post on Microsoft site and there are not recent updates. I post this as an answer to encourage people to give alternative solutions respect to the downgrade the Office version or some update. Sorry for cross post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the 1807 Build 10325.20082 update.

Restoring to an earlier build (9330.2087) fixed the problem for me:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2770432/how-to-revert-to-an-earlier-version-of-office-2013-or-office-2016-clic

Comment: I considered downgrading but I was hoping for a more permanent solution, but since we can't do anything about it this will have suffice. Thank you

Comment: We have the same problem in our environment and It happens only when we disable the macro execution (apart the signed ones).

Is it possible that this problem is still present after so many months?

I read the forum's post on Microsoft site and there are not recent updates.

I post this as an answer to encourage people to give alternative solutions respect to the downgrade the Office version or some update.

Sorry for cross post

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten report from MVP's at the forums of microsoft that they did a server sided change to a configuration file that word downloads during startup of word. The change makes it so, so that the (new) problematic code causing (my documents.add) problem gets disabled.

I just tested it with a client that had the problem and were we downgraded the office version to the previous build and now the problem as far i could tell seems to be solved.

It could be if you update your office version again it also works with you. Potentially if the problem still occurs the 1st time you need to close word wait a bit and start again.

Maybe it is now also fixed for the documents.open problem with this (server sided) change.

More info in original discution here 
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-msoffice_custom-mso_2016/1807-build-1032520082-is-causing-vba-problems-with/538e8c3c-355e-47a7-9e3f-58cf04902c10

Comment: I tried updating with a couple of clients and it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: did you start word a second time after the upgrade ? it could still fail the 1st time after the update. If it doesn't seem to solve it for documents.open i would strongly suggest to report it on the microsoft forums about that issue as well it really looked as if it would have been the same issue

Comment: yes I restarted it a bunch of times and I waited a little bit between executions. Nothing diferent. We already contacted microsoft and we're waiting for a response.

Comment: It seems other people are reporting same problem in the ms discution as well and one of the mvp's had to downgrade again (not sure as to why i asked why). They reported the issue(s) again

Comment: We reported the problem almost two weeks ago, we where told that they would take a look at it and that we should wait at least 2 to 3 moths to report the problem again if it wasn't solved in that period. Maybe we should create a Documents.Open focused discution in the ms forum, since the documents.add is solved?

Comment: You could enter the discution on ms forums as well. The reason rich, the mvp had to downgrade again is because he also had the documents.open problem alongside the documents.add problem. He also said the documents.add problem fix doenst stick after a reboot and the 1st time using word after a reboot the documents.add problem is back until a restart of word. He contacted the ms people again about this problem so i think they are aware of the documents.open problem as well at this time.